# How can I avoid an infinite loop in useEffect in this situation

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, use-effect

I am working on building a redux app and I need data from my database to end up in my redux store after a particular component is loaded. However, I need this to happen every time a user adds new data. Currently, I can either get the data to load initially by passing an empty dependency array to my effect, but this stops the data from being updated based on user actions (you would have to refresh the page to get the effect to run again). But if I add the data to my dependency array, this causes an infinite loop because the effect would be changing the data that is being watched in the dependency array. Below is the current flow of my code.

1. `useEffect` dispatches action from `MarkerList` component.
2. Redux action retrieves data from Firestore and dispatches action to the reducer.
3. Reducer updates state with payload from Firestore.

I don't know how to correctly get my effect to trigger every time a new marker is added. If I can't track my data in the dependency array due to an infinite loop, how am I supposed to monitor changes to the data and retrigger the effect?

I have tried setting up a firestore `onSnapshot` listener but that doesn't play nicely with redux. I have tried using an empty dependency array as stated previously which correctly fetches data the first time, but does not update my ui when new data is added without refreshing the page. Obviously, tracking the markers in the dependency array causes an infinite loop.

Effect in component

```
useEffect(() => {
  const loadMarkers = async () => {
    props.loadMarkers();
  };
  loadMarkers();
}, []);
```

Redux Action

```
export function loadMarkers() {
  let markers = [];
  return dispatch => {
    getMarkersFromDB().then(snap => {
      snap.forEach(doc => {
        markers.push(doc.data());
      });
      dispatch({
        type: constants.LOAD_MARKERS,
        payload: markers
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: What else is triggering the `loadMarkers` action to be dispatched? It makes sense to me to kick off `loadMarkers` when the component mounts but it's unclear to me what else would signal that there are new markers. You could either poll and call `loadMarkers` on an interval or you need some listener to trigger `loadMarkers` when you know there is a new one.

Comment: Nothing currently triggers loadMarkers besides that effect. Users have the option to add new markers (which get placed on the ui and stored in the DB). What I would like is for the new marker to appear on the ui as soon as the user submits a new marker creation. However, I cant put the markers array as a dependency because that triggers an infinite loop. I am not sure how to implement a listener with redux

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I was so wrapped around trying to figure out how to make the effect handle all data manipulations, I didn't think to just call loadMarkers again from the function that adds a marker to my database. The CreateMarker component is separate so I just wired it up to redux and passed the loadMarkers action to it. Now, my MarkerList still loads the initial data on mount, but whenever a user creates a new marker, the CreateMarker components also dispatches the loadMarkers action. Everything is working now.

Thanks Azundo, talking through it with you made me realize I was being shortsighted.

Comment: Yep, that sounds right! Was going to suggest that or setting up an `onSnapshot` listener in a `componentDidMount` that dispatches the `LOAD_MARKERS` action on each snapshot - it will run once when it's first set up then again anytime the db changes. You could do this on your root component for example and then you would also get updates if someone or something other than the current user changed a value in the marker collection.